# Get Doctrine discriminator values

Tags: doctrine, discriminator

I'm currently developing a new feature on my website and I created this parent class:

```
/**
 * CustomPageSuggestedContent
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "Book" = "CustomPageSuggestedBook",
 *     "Training" = "CustomPageSuggestedTraining"
 * })
 */
abstract class CustomPageSuggestedContent
{
  ...
}
```

I'd like to get all the discriminator values. It this possible?
The optimal solution for me would be to have a static function inside my class that returns "Book" and "Training" in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, I needed to go a level higher, in a controller. This code returns the disriminator map:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(CustomPageSuggestedContent::class);
$discriminatorMap = $classMetadata->discriminatorMap;
```